# Is it possible to run an FxCop Code Analysis from the MSBuild command line with VS NOT installed?

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop

Our final build server does not have Visual Studio 2010 installed.  It uses the MSBuild.exe from the .NET 4 SDK.  As part of our code delivery process to our customer we need to allow him to build the projects from the command line on a Visual Studio 'agnostic' server and also to run Code Analysis rules on that machine.

On the visual studio side we started out with AllRules.rules and created exceptions going foreward so naturally we'd like the exceptions to carry over to the code analysis on the build server.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using standalone FxCop you can customize your CI process as you wish. Open [this link](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/miscellaneous/continuous-code-analysis-fx-cop-805/) and go to "Setting up continuous FxCop code analysis" chapter.

Link above seems to be dead now. You can try to look here [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729066/running-code-analysis-fxcop-12-0-on-build-agent-without-installing-visual-stud)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729066/running-code-analysis-fxcop-12-0-on-build-agent-without-installing-visual-stud this is more up to date