# MsBuild error MSB1025 - System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow not found (following fake generation problems)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, microsoft-fakes

I have a problem with the standard `MSBuild.exe` used on our Team Build server, the standard version used is in

- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319", version 4.0.30319.18408 or
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" respectively (same version).

Using this version leads to `Fake` dlls not being generated in the same way as on our local development machines (i.e. some fake methods are missing on the server), resulting in broken builds (unit tests) on the TFS.

I updated the build definition template to use the `MSBuild` version located under "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin" as it is more recent (version 12.0.30723.0), however, this results in an error `MSB1025`, *System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a* not found.

**Update**

Further investigation - manually adding the `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` with the correct version number to the `MSBuild` directory results in a broken build with

*Unsupported ToolsVersion 12.0*

Manually setting the `ToolVersion` in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Acitvities.MSBuild` element to `"4.0"` results in a broken build with

*Cannot set unknown member "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.MSBuild.ToolVersion"*

So... no real improvement.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fakes` is sensitive to the Visual Studio version. Try passing `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` to MSBuild arguments. Also avoid handling System.* assemblies manually.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick.I had to use a forward slash though in the textbox of the build definition (/p:existingSetting=existingValue;VisualStudioVersion=12.0). However, the build cannot perform code analysis now (I had to turn it off) as I get an error message that *"msbuild could not locate the code analysis tools at '')*, I'll have to further investigate as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729066/running-code-analysis-fxcop-12-0-on-build-agent-without-installing-visual-stud. The build also doesn't run any unit tests (starts the test run but can't find any tests).

Comment: That's a different issue. You may need to install both VS 2015 and VS 2013 on the build server.