# FxCop 12.0 for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, fxcop

Microsoft Stopped providing FxCop 12.0 separately.It comes bundled with VS 2013 and we are using VS 2012 on our build machines.So is it possible to get FxCop 12.0 with out installing VS 2013? If so please suggest.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you can do is the same as [shown in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731245/684096).

This works on both the client computer and the build server. Does not require a VS installation on the build server.