# FxCop analysis failing with MsBuild Sonar Runner

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, fxcop

I am trying to scan a .NET code using MsBuild Sonar-Runner plugin from jenkins. The system details are as:

- **Jenkins** : 1.651.2
- **Sonarqube version**: 5.6.1
- **C# plugin on Sonarqube**:5.3.2
- **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild**: SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1
- **FxCop installation**:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe
- **MSBuild installation** - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe

Using default SonarDB so no changes in sonar.properties file.

Error:  **FxCop must be installed when some of its rules are enabled in the SonarQube quality profile. FxCop is included as part of Visual Studio.**

FxCop command is able to be executed from jenkins as well as command line on sonar server, but the MsBuild faisl with this error.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fault lies in your fxcop configurations .

[Running Code Analysis (FxCop 12.0 / 14.0) on build agent without installing Visual Studio 2013 / 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729066/running-code-analysis-fxcop-12-0-14-0-on-build-agent-without-installing-visu)

this link can help you re-config all the steps required