# MSBuild could not locate the Code Analysis tool

Tags: .net, msbuild, fxcop, build-server

My Jenkins job is failing with below error logs. Please suggest.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(289,5): error : MSBuild could not locate the Code Analysis tool at ''. If MSBuild is being run from within the "Visual Studio Command Prompt", specify the path to the Code Analysis tool by setting the FXCOPDIR environment variable. [C:\test.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\test.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

[image]

Updated error logs

```
directory:"C:\OTA\AirSearch\BTS\src\packages\HttpWebAdapters.0.4.0.2002\lib\net35" /ruleSet:"=C:\OTA\AirSearch\BTS\.sonarqube\conf\\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset" /rule:"-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules" /searchgac /ignoreinvalidtargets /forceoutput /successfile /ignoregeneratedcode /saveMessagesToReport:Active,Excluded /timeout:120 /reportMissingIndirectAssemblies 
  * Error(s) occurred during FxCop initialization: 
  * An exception was raised attempting to load engine 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\team tools\static analysis tools\fxcop\Engines\PhoenixAnalysisEngine.dll'.

  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
     at Microsoft.FxCop.Command.FxCopCommand.ProcessPlatformArgument(ArgumentDictionary argumentDictionary)
     at Microsoft.FxCop.Command.FxCopCommand.Main2(String[] args)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(289,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "FxCopCmd.exe" could not be run. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\test.csproj]
  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Done Building Project "C:\test.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (843,131)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Done Building Project "C:\test.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Which code analysis tool has failed? SonarCube?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I feel its SonarQube

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on your screenshot you need to specify the path to your favorite code analysis tool explicitely in your msbuild-call ( like c.\program files\sonacube ... ) or by addind the path to it to your PATH environment-variable ( see [How to add path to PATH-env-var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) )

And you should make sure that all dependecies from VS-FXCop could be located and resolved. Best way to do so is to call the visual studio var bat ( on my installation it can be located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat for VS2015 ). Please make sure that you call the right script. If you have copied the FxCop stuff from a different visual studio installation use this script. If you have installed it from your redistributable make sure that you have copied all dependencies as well.

Comment: Could you please help me in this

Comment: Hard without the complete raw log. It would be useful if you can upload it somehow.

Comment: After following below and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729066/running-code-analysis-fxcop-12-0-14-0-on-build-agent-without-installing-visu i got updated error.